# Override the plugin class and function

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

hope somebody could help me. I have bought one plugin. But I need to change the function of the plugin in my child template functions.php
Here is the classes and functions of the plugin. I need to change the function "get_product_price" with my value.

```
class TOP_Woo {
  public function __construct() {
    ..
    ..
    $this->init_hook();
  }

  public function init_hook() {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', array( $this, 'my_product_class' ), 10, 4 );
  }

  public function my_product_class( $classname, $product_type, $post_type, $product_id) {
    $classname = 'SUB_WC_Product';
    return $classname;
  }

  public function load() {
    TOP_Woo::instance();
  }

  public static function instance() {
    if ( ! self::$_instance ) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'TOP_Woo', 'load' ) );


global $woocommerce;
class SUB_WC_Product extends WC_Product_Simple {
  public function __construct ( $product = 0 ) {
    $this->post = get_post( $this->id );
  }

  public function get_product_price( $context = 'view' ) {
    return "XY";
  }
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would allow you to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

thanks... I dont know if is this good way, but this code in the child theme functions.php is working for me:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_class', 'myFunction', 10, 4);
function myFunction($classname, $product_type, $post_type, $product_id) {
    $classname = 'SUB_WC_Product_my';
    return $classname;
}

class SUB_WC_Product_my extends SUB_WC_Product {
    public function get_product_price( $context = 'view' ) {
        return "AB";
    }
}
```